# Combine two characters in all possible ways without itertools to a certain length in Python

Tags: python, string, combinations

I want to generate strings with all possible combinations of two characters of a certain length. For example, if I want to generate all the strings of length 3 with characters `'a'` and `'b'` I want the next output (not in a list):

```
aaa
aab
aba
baa
bbb
bba
abb
bbb
```

I had defined two functions:

```
def replace(string,char):
    y = string[1] 
    for i in range(1,len(string)):
        string = string[:i].replace(y,char) + string[i:]
        print(string)

def powerset(char1,char2,longitud):
"""FUnction to get all the combinations
of two characters of a certain length """
    x = char1*longitud
    print (x)
    replace(x, char2)
    y = char2* longitud
    replace(y, char1)
    print (y)
```

If I run the code with a lenth of 3 I get only 6 of the 8 combinations:

```
powerset('a','b',3)
aaa
baa
bba
abb
aab
bbb
```

I'm still missing the `bab` and `aba` combinations. If I put 4 in my powerset function I get 8 of the 16 possible combinations. There should be an easiest way of solving the problem but I'm stuck. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You can use `itertools.product`.

Comment: If you are going to specify "without itertools" please specify why you can't use itertools.

Comment: If your teacher forbids you from importing itertools, you can always copy-paste the "roughly equivalent to:" code blocks from their documentation :-)

Comment: Have you seen the example implementation in the [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) documentation?  It's not as efficient as the reference implementation, but it should produce identical results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple recursive [generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
def combos(chars, length):
  if length == 0:
    yield ''
    return
  for char in chars:
    for combo in combos(chars, length-1):
      yield char + combo

>>> list(combos('ab', 3))
['aaa', 'aab', 'aba', 'abb', 'baa', 'bab', 'bba', 'bbb']
```

Comment: The `return` statement isn't necessary.

Comment: @chepner I think it is. Where else is the base case?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I was seeing an `else` that isn't there.